# Automatically adjust rows height

Tags: tables, nicematrix

Very simple MWE is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=2.00cm, top=3.00cm, bottom=2.00cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{nicematrix, tikz}
\begin{document}

\centering

\begin{NiceTabular}{c|l|r|}
\cline{2-3}
\Block{5-1}{\rotate Long enough text} & Text 1 & 1 \\
\cline{2-3}
& Text 2 & 2\\
\cline{2-3}
& Text 3 & 3\\
\cline{2-3}
& Text 4 & 4\\
\cline{2-3}
& Text 5 & 5\\
\cline{2-3}
\end{NiceTabular}   
    
\end{document}
```

Is it possible to automatically adjust (increase here) height of rows in columns 2 and 3?

[image]

Comment: At this time, it's not possible to do that automatically with `nicematrix` (maybe in a future version). You should try `tabularray`.

Comment: @F.Pantigny, thanks about pointing to tabularray. I sow in its manual this is possible. But, as I wrote in my other question, unfortunately it has problems with colored cells.

Comment: @Alx I am fixing the colored cells problem in `tabularray`.  Just wait for the next version scheduled on September 1st.

Comment: Are you interested in a non-automatic, but simple solution?

Comment: @Fran, probably yes, you may suggest your solution.

Answer (score 4):

With `nicematrix` it is possible to change the height of all the cells.

For a manual adjustment use
`\begin{NiceTabular}{c|l|r|}[cell-space-limits=<number>pt]`
and change the `number` until the vertical text fits.  For your posted example `\begin{NiceTabular}{c|l|r|}[cell-space-limits=5pt]` will do.

It is also possible *to calculate* the additional height required, by measuring the width of the text line to rotate and the height of `NiceTabular`.

Then dividing the difference of those two values between the rows of the `NiceTabular` is a good approximation. (It fails with a single row)

The `\fitVcell` macro requires three parameters to do that job: #1 the `NiceTabular`; #2 the text to rotate; and #3 the number of rows. The output will print a `NiceTabular`, now expanded to fit the vertical text.

[image: a]

(In the last tabular the horizontal lines were extended and an x was added to verify the alignment.)

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
%\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{unicode-math}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=2.00cm, top=3.00cm, bottom=2.00cm]{geometry}
%\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{nicematrix} % only package needed <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
%%********************** added 
\newlength{\myNT}   
\newlength{\WofT}
\newcommand{\fitVcell}[3]{% #1 NiceTabular %2 vertical text #3 number of rows
 {\NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-limits = 0pt}   
\settoheight{\myNT}{#1} 
\settowidth{\WofT}{#2}  
\addtolength{\WofT}{-\myNT}
\divide\WofT by#3
\divide\WofT by 2
\NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-limits = \WofT}
#1}
}
%%**********************

\begin{document}
\centering  
    
\textbf{Original MWE, 5 rows} and   \texttt{Long enough text}\bigskip

\fitVcell{%
    \begin{NiceTabular}{c|l|r|}
        \cline{2-3}
        \Block{5-1}{\rotate Long enough text} & Text 1 & 1 \\
        \cline{2-3}
        & Text 2 & 2\\
        \cline{2-3}
        & Text 3 & 3\\
        \cline{2-3}
        & Text 4 & 4\\
        \cline{2-3}
        & Text 5 & 5\\
        \cline{2-3}
    \end{NiceTabular}  
}
{Long enough text}{5}
        
\bigskip
\textbf{Longer text, 5 rows} and    \texttt{Long enough text much longer}\bigskip

\fitVcell{%
        \begin{NiceTabular}{c|l|r|}
        \cline{2-3}
        \Block{5-1}{\rotate Long enough text much longer} & Text 1 & 1 \\
        \cline{2-3}
        & Text 2 & 2\\
        \cline{2-3}
        & Text 3 & 3\\
        \cline{2-3}
        & Text 4 & 4\\
        \cline{2-3}
        & Text 5 & 5\\
        \cline{2-3}
    \end{NiceTabular}  
}
{Long enough text much longer}{5}

\bigskip

\textbf{Longer text, 2 rows} and    \texttt{Long enough text much longer x}\bigskip

\fitVcell{% Two rows
    \begin{NiceTabular}{c|l|r|}
        \cline{1-3} %changed to test alignment
        \Block{2-1}{\rotate Long enough text much longer x} & Text 1 & 1 \\ % Block 2 x 1 <<<<
        \cline{2-3}
        & Text 2 & 2\\
        \cline{1-3} %changed to test alignment
%       & Text 3 & 3\\
%       \cline{2-3}
%       & Text 4 & 4\\
%       \cline{2-3}
%       & Text 5 & 5\\
%       \cline{2-3}
    \end{NiceTabular}
}
{Long enough text much longer x}{2}
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

A non-automatic solution:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}
\extrarowheight1em
\begin{NiceTabular}{c|l|r|}
\cline{2-3}
\Block{5-1}{\rotate Long enough text} & Text 1 & 1 \\[1em]
\cline{2-3}
& Text 2 & 2\\[1em]
\cline{2-3}
& Text 3 & 3\\[1em]
\cline{2-3}
& Text 4 & 4\\[1em]
\cline{2-3}
& Text 5 & 5\\[1em]
\cline{2-3}
\end{NiceTabular}   
\end{document}
```

Comment: Much simpler is to use `\begin{NiceTabular}{c|l|r|}[cell-space-limits=5pt]`

Comment: @SimonDispa Only if you read the manual   (BTW, +1 for doing this).

Comment: The manual is fine. The only problem is that gets updated frequently. :-)